# Problema ao recuperar listas firebase utilizando mobx

Tags: flutter

**Considerando que tenho um produto com vários itens/complementos carregados do firebase..**

Sendo que cada item desses tem um checkbox para marcar se o usuário vai adicionar esse item ao pedido ou não. E, o controle de estado é feito utilizando o mobx para refazer somente o item que foi alterado.

Porém, com uma lista de complementos funciona perfeitamente, o problema é quando tenho mais de um complemento (com vários itens) o mobx perde a referência de qual lista está sendo referida e acaba dando bug ao selecionar um item da lista.

**Lista de complementos:**

```
recuperarComplementos(){
    //print("chamou recuperar complementos");

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("complementos")
        .doc(widget.produto.idProduto)
        .collection("complementos")
        .orderBy("posicao")
        .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){

        switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return carregandoDados;
            break;
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;

            if(querySnapshot.docs.length == 0){
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Nenhum complemento!",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
              );
            }

            return Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ListView.builder(
                //reverse: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: querySnapshot.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, indice){

                  List<DocumentSnapshot> complementos = querySnapshot.docs.toList();
                  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = complementos[indice];
                  Complemento complemento = Complemento.fromDocumentSnapshot(documentSnapshot);

                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      listaItensComplemento(complemento),
                    ],
                  );

                },
              ),
            );

        }
        return Container();
      },
    );

  }
```

**Lista de itens do complemento:**

```
listaItensComplemento(Complemento complemento){
   
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("complementos")
          .doc(widget.produto.idProduto)
          .collection("complementos")
          .doc(complemento.idComplemento)
          .collection("itens")
          .orderBy("posicao", descending: false)
          //.limit(3)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){

        switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return carregandoDados;
            break;
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;

            if(querySnapshot.docs.length == 0){
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Nenhum item disponível!",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),),
                ),
              );
            }

            return Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ListView.builder(
                //reverse: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: querySnapshot.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, indice){
                  //print(indice);
                  List<DocumentSnapshot> complementos =
                    querySnapshot.docs.toList();
                  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = complementos[indice];
                  final ItemComplemento itemComplemento =
                    ItemComplemento.fromDocumentSnapshot(documentSnapshot);

                  Map<String, dynamic> novoItem = {
                    "marcou": false,
                    "titulo": 5,
                  };
                  itemComplemento.marcado = false;
                  itemComplementoModel.addItem(novoItem);

                  if(indice == 0){
                    return Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        CardComplemento(complemento),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            PartComplemento(
                              indice: indice,
                              itemComplemento: itemComplemento,
                              carrinhoModel: carrinhoModel,
                              itemComplementoModel: itemComplementoModel,
                              complemento: complemento,
                            ),
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                                child: Divider(color: Colors.grey[300],)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    );

                  }

                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      PartComplemento(
                        indice: indice,
                        itemComplemento: itemComplemento,
                        carrinhoModel: carrinhoModel,
                        itemComplementoModel: itemComplementoModel,
                        complemento: complemento
                      ),
                      Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                          child: Divider(color: Colors.grey[300],)),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            );

        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
```

**Item Complemento Model (mobx):**

```
abstract class _ItemComplementoModel with Store{

  @observable
  ObservableList<Map<String, dynamic>> listaItens = ObservableList<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  @observable
  int qtdSelecionada = 0;

  @action
  void addItem(Map<String, dynamic> novoItem){
    listaItens.add(novoItem);
  }

  @action
  void marcarItem(
      {int indice,
      bool marcou,
      CarrinhoModel carrinhoModel,
      ItemComplemento itemComplemento,
      Complemento complemento
      }){

      if(marcou == true){
        listaItens[indice] = {"marcou": true};
        qtdSelecionada++;
      }else{
        listaItens[indice] = {"marcou": false};
        qtdSelecionada--;
      }

  }


}
```

**Minha dúvida é, como poderia adicionar uma lista dentro do mobx para cada complemento de forma automática utilizando firebase, para aí sim o mobx saber a referência de cada complemento e seus respectivos itens..**